# Action of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on the projective plane over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: finite-fields, group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry, projective-space

The group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ act on the projective spaces $P(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and the upper half of the complex plane $\mathbb{H}$ by linear fractional transformations. I am wondering whether there is a direct connection between these actions.

For example: Is there a natural projection $\mathbb{H}\rightarrow P(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ or an embedding $P(\mathbb{Z}_p)\rightarrow\mathbb{H}$ which agrees with the action? Also, the points of $P(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ could be placed as the vertices of a $p$-gon plus a point at infinity; is there a connection with the disk model of $\mathbb{H}$ so that the natural action on the disk induces the action on $P(\mathbb{Z}_p)$?

Comment: In the p-adic world, the hyperbolic plane is replaced by a valence $p+1$ tree, whose ideal boundary is the $p$-adic projective line (just like the boundary of the hyperbolicplane is the real projective line). You can read more in Serre's book "Trees."

Comment: Your choice of tags somehow suggests that may be $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is the finite field of $p$ elements for you, but in this context it might also be the ring of $p$-adic integers. Please clarify which is the case! The answerer seems to assume the finite field, but Moishe Kohan is thinking $p$-adics. I may have erred in interpreting either or both of those contributions, but anyway. They both seem to know more about this topic. The clarification would be for my benefit (unless one of the others misinterpreted).

Comment: Yes, I assumed $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are the integers modulo $p$ because I can imagine the points of the projective line over integers modulo $p$ "could be placed as the vertices of a $p$-gon plus a point at infinity", but cannot think of a way of doing that for $p$-adic integers.

Comment: In my question, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are the integers modulo $p$. I am still trying to understand, what Moishe Kohan and colt_browning are saying. I just need to work out, how exactly $\mathbb{Z}_p$ sits in the boundary.

Comment: It's the projective line over $\mathbb{Q}$ which sets in the boundary. Would you like me to explain how?

Comment: Thank you, I want to work out it by myself for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The intermediate is the projective line over $\mathbb{Q}$. There is a natural projection from the projective line over $\mathbb{Q}$ onto $P(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, and also the projective line over $\mathbb{Q}$ is naturally embedded into the boundary of $\mathbb{H}$.